# Как установить опции min-max validator.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mongoose

Начал изучение Node JS + mongoose и наткнулся на проблему при валидации данных в модели.
Вот код:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import validator from 'validator';

const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            validate: [validator.isEmail, 'invalid email'],
            require: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            validate: [validator.isLength, { min: 3 }],
            require: true
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        avatarURL: String,
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

export default mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema)
```

Строка:

```
validate: [validator.isLength, { min: 3 }],
```

Валидатор isLength постоянно отдает TRUE т.к. в default значение min=0

Ну и собственно когда я пытаюсь его изменить то данное свойство не применяется.

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

P.S.
Из вариантов решения напрашивается:

```
firstName: {
            type: String,
            validate: (arr) => {
                return validator.isLength(arr, { min: 2, max: 30 })
            },
            require: true
        },
```

Но хочется более лаконичного решения...

Comment: Почему в вопросе express, а в коде mongoose? Какие входные данные?

Comment: Почему в вопросе express: =( Извиняюсь.  express также используется.{
 "email": "test@exaple.com",
 "password": "12345678",
 "firstName": "",
 "lastName": ""
}

Comment: Данная проверка в любом случае пропускает пустое значение в документ.